# how to know or compute the current chunk size for a mongodb shard?

Tags: mongodb

in fact the following is what i really want to ask:
the set of chunk size is 1M. when a config server down, the whole config servers are readonly. current cluster have only a chunk, if I want to insert a lot of data to this cluster, the capacity of these data is more than 1M, Can I successfully insert these data?
if yes, do it describe that the real chunk size can more than the set of chunk size?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** yes you can, but you should fix your config server(s) asap to avoid unbalancing your shards for long.

---

Chunks are split automatically when they reach their size threshold - [stated here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+Administration#ShardingAdministration-ChunkSizeConsiderations).

However, during a config server failure, chunks cannot be split. Even if just one server fails. [See here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding+and+Failover).

**Edits**

As stated by [Sergio Tulentsev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125816/sergio-tulentsev), you should fix your config server(s) before performing your insert. The system's metadata will continue to be readonly until then.

As [Adam C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1148648/adam-c)'s link points out, your shard will become unbalanced if you were to perform an insert like you describe before fixing your config server(s).

Comment: yes, I know it is automatic, but current the config servers are readonly. so this chunk can't be splitted

Comment: Fix config servers and then do your massive insert.

Comment: Also asked (and answered) here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/iB1lsdl9UC0

Comment: This question was answered a long time ago (2012).  Since then MongoDB has changed the config server deployment topology.  Rather than using mirrored servers (SCCC) they now use a replica set (CSRS).  As a result I believe the system can a minority config server outage and continue to split (as long as a majority of voting writable nodes are available) - see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-config-servers/